# How to delete a document from a collection in cosmos db using Java?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How can I delete a document from a collection.

```
AsyncDocumentClient client = getDBClient();
   RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
   options.setPartitionKey(new PartitionKey("143003"));
   client.deleteDocument(String.format("dbs/test-lin/colls/application/docs/%s", document.id()), options);
```

I am trying to delete a set of documents from collection based on some condition. I have set the partition key. The read-write keys are being used (So no permission issue).
There are no errors when executing this code. The document is not getting deleted from the collection.
How to fix the issue?

Comment: Can you try by changing the following code `String.format("dbs/test-lin/colls/application/docs/%s", document.id())` to `String.format("/dbs/test-lin/colls/application/docs/%s", document.id())`? Essentially I added a `/` before `dbs`.

Comment: So,could you make sure the document you want to delete residents in the `143003` partition exactly?

Comment: @JayGong , the document is part of the partition key .

Comment: @GauravMantri , no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Suj Patil
You should call subscribe(). The publisher does not do anything until some one subscribes.

`client.deleteDocument(String.format("dbs/test-lin/colls/application/docs/%s", document.id()), options).subscribe()`